# SafeArgs and View Binding properties visibility

Tags: kotlin, android-navigation, android-viewbinding

This question could be applied to many other cases.

In a android fragment class implemented with Kotlin, it's common to see this using View Binding and SafeArgs:

```kotlin
class MyFragment: Fragment(){
    var _binding: MyFragmentBinding? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!
    val args: MyFragmentArgs by navArgs()
    val data = args.data 
[...]
```

Why are not private these properties? It's not a bad pattern to expose my properties to another classes if it's not needed?

Comment: Common where? Who's code is this? Generally, yes, it's better to encapsulate things and make them private, but this is an opinion-based question, so it can't be answered suitably on this site.

Comment: Is the way proposed by android.developers guides https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding?hl=es-419#fragments and https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/use-graph/pass-data

Comment: Between those two links I only see one line of code with that anti pattern. It’s probably a mistake.

Comment: You're right... i have followed incorrectly the view binding guide. I'm going to use private also for Safe args properties if it's possible. Thanks